# how to sending jquery in mail function using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to send a html in mail with jquery tooltip. The html is working fine but the jquery tooltip doesn't show up with the HTML.  my code is

```
require_once("config.php");

$to= "something@yahoo.com";
$subject= "Todays follow up status from Murree Hotels Website";

$query= "select * from honymoon_enquries WHERE arrival_date BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW())+7 order by arrival_date";

$res=mysql_query($query);

$message = "<strong>Hi Admin <br><br> </strong>";

$message .= "<strong> Here is the list of all clients coming in next seven(7) days.<br><br> </strong>";

$message .="
<link rel='stylesheet' href='jquery-tooltip/jquery.tooltip.css'/>
<script src='jquery-tooltip/lib/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jquery-tooltip/lib/jquery.bgiframe.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jquery-tooltip/lib/jquery.dimensions.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jquery-tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script src='jquery-tooltip/demo/chili-1.7.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
$('#right *').tooltip({ 
    track: true,
    delay: 100,
    showURL: false,
    extraClass: 'right'
});

$('#right2 a').tooltip({ showURL: false, positionLeft: true });

$('#block').click($.tooltip.block);

});
</script>
<table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;'> 
    <tr> 
    <td> 
        <div style='border:1px solid #CCCCCC; padding:10px; padding-top:5px; text-align:center'> 
<div>           
<table width='100%' border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='3'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Arival_Date</th>
<th>Adminfeedback</th>
</tr>
";      
while ($resresult = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

$message .="
<tr BGCOLOR='99CCFF'>
<td>".$resresult['client_name']."</td>
<td>".$resresult['client_email']."</td>
<td>".$resresult['client_phone']."</td>
<td>".$resresult['arrival_date']."</td>
<td align='left' title='".$resresult['adminfeedback']."' style='cursor:help;'>".$resresult['adminfeedback']."</td>
";      
}
$message .="</table></div></td> </tr> </table></div>" ;


$headers = "From: sales@murreehotels.net"."\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


if (!mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
   die("Message sending failed");
}
```

Comment: your want a javascript tooltip in the email? short answer - you can't. big security issue if email clients allowed js, so they don't.

Comment: no can do. javascript in an email is a no go.

Comment: He can, email can contain HTML and JavaScript

Comment: try to set your message with html tags, and you didn't include the jquery lib in the message, try doing this changes

Comment: @Dani care to show proof of JS inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't. Mail clients strip out JS. It's next to impossible to include an external stylesheet in some clients let alone JS

Comment: hi so we dont send jquey in mail fuction?:))

Comment: @shoaibakhunzada yup. You don't send it. You should read this article on good guidelines for HTML emails : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/design-guidelines/

Answer (score 1):

Email clients generally strip out or don't process JavaScript and for good reason.

Just stick with plain HTML and the subset of CSS that works over majority of mail clients.

Answer (score 1):

Email clients will not parse/execute JavaScript. If they did, it would lead to all kinds of unpleasant security issues. What you are trying to achieve is not possible my friend.